# Can i use ng-show with display:none?

Tags: css, angularjs

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ICFx5PUeVJ0iYLmZCgS8?p=preview), what is happening is that always when i refresh the page, even if the ng-show is "false", it always show something for a milliseconds. 
 I know why this is happening, it happens because angular hasn't been loaded yet, so i want to use a css property "display:none" to avoid this, but it still isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [ng-cloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak).
For example:

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
```

This will prevent the browser from displaying the `"#template1"` div during the brief time the `hello` scope model don't have any value.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a the [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive (and its CSS) that is designed specifically for this purpose

Hope this helps